# Cropper.js - The first argument is required and must be an <img> or <canvas> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, cropperjs

I'm totally new to JS and I'm trying to use [Cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs). I couldn't run the given example on README either. This is the code that I'm trying to run:

```js
//import Cropper from 'cropperjs';

let image = document.getElementById('img');
const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  crop(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.x);
    console.log(event.detail.y);
    console.log(event.detail.width);
    console.log(event.detail.height);
    console.log(event.detail.rotate);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
  },
});
```

```css
img {

    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cropper Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.6/cropper.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.6/cropper.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img id="img" src="test.png"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I uncomment the import statement, in console it shows : Cannot use import statement outside a module.
I did search here for this problem but couldn't find anything that fixes my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use image[0] as the first input argument of Cropper class and it can solve your problem.

```
const cropper = new Cropper(image[0], {
 aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
 crop(event) {
   console.log(event.detail.x);
   console.log(event.detail.y);
   console.log(event.detail.width);
   console.log(event.detail.height);
   console.log(event.detail.rotate);
   console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
   console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
 },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - the problem was such that the JavaScript file was getting loaded before the DOM is fully loaded. Hence, reference 'img' kept failing since it was requested before the actual image was loaded. Also, I thank [Sarfraaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12661767/sarfraaz) for pointing out about references.

FIX :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cropper Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.6/cropper.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.6/cropper.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img id="img" src="test.png"/>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it works as expected, it might be the issue with the image you are trying to load

```js
/* import Cropper from 'cropperjs';
 */
let image = document.getElementById('img');
const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  crop(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.x);
    console.log(event.detail.y);
    console.log(event.detail.width);
    console.log(event.detail.height);
    console.log(event.detail.rotate);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
  },
});
```

```css
img {

    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cropper Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.6/cropper.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.6/cropper.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img id="img" src="https://patadev.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com//profile/1576322838400hdiqdcjlxs.png"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't work. The same error persists.

Comment: Check the runnable solution, I have updated & added full runnable code here

Comment: Thanks, it looks like yours and mine works here and also on JSFiddle. But I can't get this to work on my browsers (tried Chrome, Firefox and Edge). I keep getting this error. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: This is what I get:
Error: The first argument is required and must be an <img> or <canvas> element.
    at new Cropper (cropper.js:3217)
    at test.js:4

If this isn't what you meant, please let me know how to get what you're asking for. I'm relatively new to JavaScript.

Comment: This is mostly because the image is not found with the id `img` in your html. Please check & make sure you're getting the correct reference to it

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* import Cropper from 'cropperjs';
 */
let image = document.getElementById('img');
const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  crop(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.x);
    console.log(event.detail.y);
    console.log(event.detail.width);
    console.log(event.detail.height);
    console.log(event.detail.rotate);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
  },
});
```

```css
img {

    display: block;
    ma%;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cropper Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.6/cropper.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.5.6/cropper.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img id="img" src="https://patadev.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com//profile/1576322838400hdiqdcjlxs.png"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.
It may happen because it can't find the particular time. when component loads

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const cropper = new Cropper(
    <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("image"),
    {
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      crop(event) {
        console.log(event.detail.x);
        console.log(event.detail.y);
        console.log(event.detail.width);
        console.log(event.detail.height);
        console.log(event.detail.rotate);
        console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
        console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
      }
    }
  );
}, 1000);
```